# How to add Google fonts locally

Tags: theming

At the moment, I have this in my template.php

```
drupal_add_css('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Short+Stack',array('type' => 'external'));
```

I now have the .woff is the theme's folder. What's the proper way to add it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) or a similar tool to download **all** possible font formats (only `*.woff` won't be enough regarding cross-browser compatibility).
2. Store the font files somewhere in your theme, maybe in a subfolder called `/fonts`.
3. Use `@font-face` in your CSS to load the fonts as described in this brilliant CSS-Tricks article: [Using @font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

---

> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'MyWebFont';
>   src: url('../fonts/webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
>   src: url('../fonts/webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
>        url('../fonts/webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
>        url('../fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
>        url('../fonts/webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
>        url('../fonts/webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
> }
>
> body {
>   font-family: 'MyWebFont', SomeFallbackFont, sans-serif;
> }
> ```